# How can I detect if UI orientation is locked or not on iOS?

Tags: ios, locking, orientation, detection

Is it possible to detect UI orientation is locked or not currently? If so, how can I do that?

I want to do something with gravity sensor when only UI orientation is not locked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS device orientation disregarding orientation lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574693/ios-device-orientation-disregarding-orientation-lock)

Answer (score 2):

Not possible unfortunately, the lock is handled by the OS and is transparent to the app.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try calling the shouldAutorotate method and see what BOOL value is returned?

I haven't tried looking for the UIOrientation lock. But off the top of my head, this is how I'd try.

```
if([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft])
    NSLog(@"Rotates LandscapeLeft");

if([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight])
    NSLog(@"Rotates LandscapeRight");

if([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
    NSLog(@"Rotates Portrait");

if([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown])
    NSLog(@"Rotates PortraitUpsideDown");
```

Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: This doesn't work as shouldAutorotate is not called when the lock is enabled

Comment: it "should not" work if the lock is enabled. If you want to know the rotation, then you should be using UIDeviceOrientation.