# Problems with AVCaptureSession in landscape mode on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, device-orientation, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I have been trying to capture frames from front camera and present it on the view. Here is my code

```
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
_session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:device error:&error];

if (deviceInput) {
    [_session addInput:deviceInput];
}
else {
    DDLogInfo(@"Some wierd shit happened");
    return;
}

// Session output
/*
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[_session addOutput:output];
output.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeFace];
AVCaptureConnection *connection = [output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeMetadata];
connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
*/

// Session output
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *videoOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
[_session addOutput:videoOutput];
AVCaptureConnection *connection = [videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;

// Preview layer
_previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
_previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
_previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.middleView.frame.size.width, self.middleView.frame.size.height);
[self.middleView.layer addSublayer:_previewLayer];

[_session startRunning];
```

Problem with this is, when my iPad is landscape, the images on presentation layer are rotated 90 degrees. How do i fix this? I have been browsing stack overflow, trying to do something with `AVCaptureConnection`, but alas to no avail.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solved it, now it is working in all orientations. We need to set this

```
_previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = [self videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation];
```

where the method is:

```
 - (AVCaptureVideoOrientation) videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation {
switch (self.interfaceOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait: {
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    }
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft: {
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: {
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown: {
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
}
}
```

Also on capture output we need to set:

```
AVCaptureConnection *output2VideoConnection = [videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
output2VideoConnection.videoOrientation = [self videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation];
```

Comment: don't forget you need to set `.connection.videoOrientation` again when the user rotates their device :)

Answer (score 14):

In **Swift 3**:

First we have to set `previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation` like MegaManX do

```
previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = self.videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation()
```

where the method is:

```
func videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation() -> AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
    switch UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation {
    case .portrait:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    case .landscapeLeft:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
    case .landscapeRight:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
    default:
        // Can this happen?
        return AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    }
}
```

Then we also have to handle the `videoOrientation` when the user rotates the device (method come from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958796/2603230))

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
        self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = self.videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation()

        }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            // Finish Rotation
    })

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

Comment: What to do when device orientation is locked? `viewWillTransitionToSize` method will not call. How to manage this. I have to detect picture orientation when device locked.

Comment: @mahbaleshwarhegde you mean despite the device orientation is locked, you still want the picture rotate with the device?

Comment: yes. when device locked i am getting statusBarOrientation is portrait. So video connection  become portrait even though i took picture in landscape mode. How to do. any idea?

Comment: @mahbaleshwarhegde try the answers in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4574693/2603230 :)

Comment: My app not have any coremotion functionality. Just for getting orientation in only one screen if i use the coremotion Apple may reject the app. Any other idea is appreciated.

Comment: @mahbaleshwarhegde how about try to force user enter a certain orientation when taking photos? :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/26357162/2603230

Comment: @mahbaleshwarhegde or maybe change the orientation of the photo to the correct one afterwards? (like iOS's "Camera" app does)