# Rotation methods deprecated, equivalent of 'didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation'?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios8

I'm trying to implement the new `viewWillTransitionToSize` method which has been introduced in iOS 8 (all other rotation methods have been deprecated). I'd like to know what the equivalent of `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` is now as there are a number of clean up tasks we need to perform and I can't see a block that we can assign to `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` in order to be called when 'transition' to a new size finishes. Thanks.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Okay found it, just have to use the `animateAlongsideTransition:completion:` method on the passed `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator`.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{   
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        // do whatever
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    { 

    }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

Comment: Will this method call every time we rotate like didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation?. Can you please share me the method you have used.   Thank you

Comment: Yes it will. This is what I do:

`- (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

  [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    // do whatever
    
  } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

  }];

  
  [super viewWillTransitionToSize: size withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator];

}`

Comment: @strange: Thats great. It would be nice if you could add the code snippet in the answer itself. It looks congested in the comment

Comment: @strange: I have another problem in iOS 8. I have a universal iOS application. This should support all the orientations in iPads and only portrait (home button down) in iPhones. But we need one particular view controller to be locked in landscape mode only in both iPads and iPhones. And once you navigate out of that view controller, it should again support the old orientations. How to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Thanks - i'll add a swift version as an answer to save people some time

Comment: Is there a way to remove the animation?

Comment: it will call when you press power button and minimize the app.

Comment: Holy hell, Apple make it hard, don't they? If it wasn't for Stack Overflow contributors such as yourself, I doubt anyone would make anything of substantial worth with the iOS APIs. It's an absolute mess at this point.

Comment: even having this "[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator]; " at the bottom makes difference

Comment: statusbarorientation is deprecated in iOS 9. What else is the option?

Comment: @DeepakSharma I'm a little late to the party, but you can use `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation`. You can also pipe this into `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)` or `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 72):

The Swift Version of the answer by strange

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

        let orient = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation

        switch orient {
        case .Portrait:
            println("Portrait")
            // Do something
        default:
            println("Anything But Portrait")
            // Do something else
        }

        }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            println("rotation completed")
    })

    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
}
```

Comment: It's strange because I put this in my ViewController, and it didn't `print` anything to my log. I guess because this method is not being called. Can you think of anything else that would need to be plugged in order for this to work?

Comment: I just added it to a empty project (Universal App) and it works fine without the need to add anything. Maybe put a log statement at the very beginning of the method and see if its being called. I cannot think of anything that you would need to add. What iOS you running?

Comment: @DogCoffee..its not getting called. Has it anything to do with Simulator?

Comment: @Saty works in simulator as well - just checked again then. Works as expected.

Comment: is there a way to do this without subclassing UIVIewController, because we are doing MVVM-C

Comment: statusbarorientation is deprecated in iOS 9. What else is the option?

Answer (score 10):

iOS 10.3 & Swift 3

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
            let orient = newCollection.verticalSizeClass

            switch orient {
            case .compact:
                print("Lanscape")///Excluding iPads!!!

            default:
                print("Portrait")
            }
        }, completion: { _ in
            print("rotation completed")
        })

        super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need animation? Can't you check 'newCollection' straight away?

Comment: @cyanide to sync animation with my

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer in **Swift 3**:

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
        let orient = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation

        switch orient {
        case .portrait:
            print("Portrait")
        // Do something
        default:
            print("Anything But Portrait")
            // Do something else
        }
    }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
      print("rotation completed")
    })

    super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
}
```

It works fine for me

Comment: Doesn't work for me on iOS 10 — it prints the old orientation, not the new one.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick because you should use `let orient = newCollection.verticalSizeClass

            switch orient {
            case .compact:
                print("Lanscape")
            // Do something
            default:
                print("Portrait")
                // Do something else
            }`

Answer (score 5):

Since the question was: what was the equivalent of `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`

I thought I'd contribute the code below:

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];
    if (previousTraitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular) {
        NSLog(@"User has rotated to landscape");
    } else if (previousTraitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact) {
        NSLog(@"User has rotated to portrait");
    }
}
@end
```

I was testing on an iPhone in the simulator, but my print statements won't get run if I test using the iPad since the traitsCollection won't change.

This is strange because this is exactly what Apple [recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITraitEnvironment/traitCollectionDidChange:):

```
- (void) traitCollectionDidChange: (UITraitCollection *) previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];
    if ((self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection.verticalSizeClass)
        || self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection.horizontalSizeClass)) {
        // your custom implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a missing bracket in the second code snippet

Comment: Does this works on iPad where both vertical and horizontal classes are Regular on full screen?

Comment: Your code is not the same as Apple's, you are only testing the vertical size class.

Comment: It's been a while, looks like the content of the link has changed.

Answer (score 3):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` is deprecated in iOS9 you have to test against [UITraitCollection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/) for various devices.

```
  override func willTransitionToTraitCollection(newCollection: UITraitCollection, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    if newCollection.containsTraitsInCollection(UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .Regular)) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Only the setter was deprecated. An Apple employee posted, "Reading the status bar orientation is not deprecated, only writing to it is. This may have been an error in how we constructed the header if you are seeing this on the getter." (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12937)

Comment: Isn't the getter also deprecated though. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarOrientation) it is.

Answer (score 1):

On the Ipad there is no trait collection change so here is how you detect the rotation from start and completion. Here is the  Swift 5   syntax:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: 
UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { [unowned self] _ in

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        print("rotation in progress")

    }) { [unowned self] _ in
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        print("rotation complete")


    }
}
```