# iOS 8 Orientation Change Detection

Tags: objective-c, ios8, orientation

Running on iOS 8, I need to change the UI when rotating my app.

Currently I am using this code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation != UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown) [self resetTabBar];

    return YES;
}
```

What I do it remove the current UI and add a new UI appropriate to the orientation. However, my issue is that this method is called about 4 times every time a single rotation is made.

What is the correct way to make changes upon orientation change in iOS 8?

Comment: Why do you use this method to change interface at all? I think it's supposed just to answer the question wheter to rotate or not. Use 'willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:' for iOS 7- and  'viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:' for iOS 8.

Comment: Just asked a question, people trying to help but didn't bother to accept an answer or comment any detail. Sorry but that's not nice.

Answer (score 26):

Timur Kuchkarov is correct, but I'll post the answer since I missed his comment the first time I checked this page.

The **iOS 8** method of detecting orientation change (rotation) is implementing the following method of the view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    // Do view manipulation here.
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

**Note:** The controller's view has *not yet transitioned* to that size at this time, so be careful if your sizing code relies on the view's current dimensions.

Comment: Also, I just noticed better details about how to use the `coordinator` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24072010/1057616).

Comment: Since this method is called when the view has not yet transitioned to the new size, what method is called after the view has transitioned to the new size?

Comment: You should have pointed out that this method does NOT fire every time there's a rotation change.  It only fires under specific circumstances of a rotation.  I use this method in my code, and depending on the interface on display, sometimes it fires, sometimes it doesn't, which is why I ALSO have to include viewWillLayoutSubviews to handle all cases.

Answer (score 20):

The `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` method is called immediately before the view has transitioned to the new size, as Nick points out. However, the best way to run code immediately *after* the view has transitioned to the new size is to use a completion block in the method:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // your code here
    }];
}
```

Thanks to the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944087/1976584) for the code and to Nick for linking to it in his comment.

Comment: How to identify whether translation is completed?

Comment: @Satyam The completion block denoted by the comment `// your code here` will run as soon as the transition has completed.

Comment: You should have pointed out that this method does NOT fire every time there's a rotation change. It only fires under specific circumstances of a rotation. I use this method in my code, and depending on the interface on display, sometimes it fires, sometimes it doesn't, which is why I ALSO have to include viewWillLayoutSubviews to handle all cases.