# Forced orientation change does not work sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

When a certain button is pressed in my app, the view should change orientation from portrait to
landscape. When the user comes back, the view controller should change back to portrait. But
sometimes the orientation doesn't change or the wrong view frame is used.

Here is my code

```
-(void)btnSignClicked:(CustomSignButton *)btn {
    isSignButtonClicked = true;
    if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0) {
        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];
    }
    selectedWaiverId = btn.customTag;

    SignatureView *obj = [[SignatureView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) delegate:self]; // Most of time got size (568,320) but some time i got (320,568), Don't know why
    [self.view addSubview:obj];
}

#pragma mark - SIGNATUREVIEW DELEGATE
-(void)removeSignatureView:(SignatureView *)signatureView {
    isSignButtonClicked = false;

    if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0)
    {
        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"]; // Some time not changed the orientation are view remaining in landscape 
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
    }

    [signatureView removeFromSuperview];
    signatureView = nil;

}
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - Rotate screen
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (isSignButtonClicked == true)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (isSignButtonClicked == true)
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
    else
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Sometimes `viewWillTransitionToSize` method is not called so I also integrate this notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

But sometimes this also does not work.

Comment: Is this method for changing orientation even documented or is it a hack?

Comment: Fairly certain "credible and/or official sources" would recommend against doing this.

Comment: it is in document @Sulthan.

Answer (score 2):

Add in AppDelegate.m file or any base controller file

```
 @implementation UINavigationController (Orientation)


- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return [(UIViewController*)[[self viewControllers] lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];

}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [(UIViewController*)[[self viewControllers] lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return [(UIViewController*)[[self viewControllers] lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

@end
```

Now put your ViewController object in UINavigationController object and push the view controller.

EX.

```
UINavigationController *obj=[[UINavigationController  alloc] initWithRootViewController:_yourViewCtrlObj];

[self presentViewController:obj.....]; 

or
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Set your desired orientation in all view controller.

Comment: I already done this all except the present and dismiss the VC because i am not using new VC for it i only present the View

Answer (score 1):

If your app uses UINavigationViewController then create a custom class for UINAvigationController Like:

//CustomNavViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomNavViewController : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end
```

//CustomNavViewController.m

```
#import "CustomNavViewController.h"
@interface CustomNavViewController ()
@end

@implementation CustomNavViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
@end
```

And Now in your AppDelegate declare a property Like:

//AppDelegate.h

```
 @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldRotate;
```

//AppDelegate.m

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if (self.shouldRotate) {
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Now you can call orientation methods to ViewController which required fix orientation Like:

//YourViewController.m

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Now here is the trick set AppDelegate shouldRotate property to true and false for desired orientation

if you are using Default Presentation for ViewController then

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate setShouldRotate:true];// Remember first update the value then present the ViewController
[self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Same as when you dismiss

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate setShouldRotate:false];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you are using storyBoards then add CustomNavViewController directly on Identity Inspector Custom class section

[image: customNav]
And after that follow above steps. Hope it's working

Comment: I already done this all except the present and dismiss the VC because i am not using new VC for it i only present the View

Answer (score 1):

When you say "When the user comes back, the view controller should change back to portrait", do you mean that the user is hitting the back button on a navigation controller? If so, I saw this issue before and posted a solution that worked for me in another SO post: [A: Locking device orientation on a view fails when going back in NavBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30515861/1394020). I remember the transition being rough but it worked.

I also wrote a [blog post](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/lock-screen-rotation-in-ios8.html) a while back that looks at some other situations around view controller orientation locking.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563954/setstatusbarorientationanimated-not-working-in-ios-6), in particular, I think you should check the conditions of your view controllers, that they meet Apple recommendations

e.g. check supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most full-screen view controller

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all your rotation changing code inside this block

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
{
     //changing orientation code + isSignButtonClicked = true (or false) 
});
```

You need not use `shouldAutorotate` and `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

As for the view frames getting wrong, you need to use autolayout constraints for each and every view you are using in this viewController even if you are creating views programmativally

Comment: it is very old code so autolayout not implement in it. I already used dispatch in code but not get success.

Comment: I too had old code, but id had to change it to autolayout to get the frames correctly. It isn't much of a pain. You can autolayout programmatically where you set frames in code. Also you need to add ViewControllerBasedOrientation in info.plist to YES

Comment: There is no option for "ViewControllerBasedOrientation" in info.plist