# Disable autorotate on a single UIViewController not working in iPad Pro

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, portrait

I want to lock single viewcontroller in iPhone and iPad. 
This below code is working perfectly in iPhone 4,5,6 iPad, iPad 2 ,iPad retina. 
But not working in iPad pro.

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Orientation)
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

This above code is written in my view controller which view controller i do not want to rotate.

Comment: What is iOS version on iPad pro

Comment: Never attempt to override methods using a category. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: I tried below solution but it is not working @Chetan

Comment: Please check this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794712/forced-orientation-change-does-not-work-sometimes/36101433#36101433 It may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this below code in view controller, which view controller u want to lock in portrait mode

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Orientation)
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
@end

#pragma mark Orientation
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    [super shouldAutorotate];
    return NO;
}
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    // Return a bitmask of supported orientations. If you need more,
    // use bitwise or (see the commented return).
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    // return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    [super preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    // Return the orientation you'd prefer - this is what it launches to. The
    // user can still rotate. You don't have to implement this method, in which
    // case it launches in the current orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

And now do this below changes in your **plist** file
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried everything. Set the right checkboxes on project info, checked full screen, overriding the right methods. They were even being called. I fixed the problem by going into info.plist and removing the orientations for iPad. Silly that they are not displayed on project info for a universal project.

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your view controller which you don't want to rotate

This will prevent any rotation.

The view controller class you don't want to rotate should have this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

The containing navigation controller class should have this.

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutoRotate];
}
```

This will only rotate to portrait

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Don't declare the both methods in view controller. One is to be declared in view Controller and one in navigation controller class. Read the answer again