# iOS detect device orientation with hardware orientation lock AND portrait only mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, orientation, device-orientation

Information:
Hardware lock on (via lock center)
App only supports portrait

Reason:
Adjusting orientation of images captured using `AVCapture` i.e. when taking a picture in landscape, adjust it so it is shown portrait when displaying it.
`AVCapture` is set to portrait (if set otherwise, the actual camera layer will rotate which is not intended).

If hardware lock is on (via control center), `UIDeviceOrientation` AND `UIInterfaceOrientation` always return portrait.

Is there a way (besides using the Accelerometer) to detect device orientation / tilt, without regarding the lock?

Comment: Seems like accelerometer is your only option. Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574693/ios-device-orientation-disregarding-orientation-lock? Looks like it's not that hard to pull off.

Comment: Yeah I have, and i implemented it and it is working fine. I do believe that they should have made a simpler method than having to access the accelerometer. And even that is deprecated, so have to start the whole CoreMotion train to get the same result, which is not pretty for an app that dont need all that machinery. There has to be an easier way... Thanks for your comment though!

Comment: can you share what you did @B-Man ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can detect if hardware lock is on or not.

Comment: I am looking for a way to detect orientation of device whether i know if the hardware lock is on or not... so i am not looking to detect if the lock is on or not at all, it should not matter in the solution i am looking for :)

Comment: Just checking where I got negative rep from, I can see now why. I deserved this.