# UIDevice.current.orientation report wrong value

Tags: ios, swift3, device-orientation, uidevice, uideviceorientation

I locked my view in portrait, but for some reason I need to know the actual device orientation, The `UIDevice.current.orientation` as documentation is saying in description `Returns the physical orientation of the device.` this var sometimes works well and return real device orientation and sometimes return protrait (which is wrong, because I rotated the device to landscape). So I expect to get real device orientation (despite I locked my view to portrait), is it a wrong expectation? If not why this inconsiste behavior is happening?

Note: I tried `UIDevice.current.endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()`, the result is the same.

Comment: I have same problem. Please give answer someone ?

Answer (score 0):

when portrait orientation lock is on, UIDevice.current.orientation always return .up

so, use motion instead:
[iOS device orientation disregarding orientation lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574693/ios-device-orientation-disregarding-orientation-lock)