# Can we know iPhone "Portrait Orientation Lock" is On/Off

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know the iPhone is currently in Portrait mode or in Landscape mode. If I forcefully do the "Portrait orientation mode" is on then there is way to know programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Is this the thing you need?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894646/3940673

Comment: I got the correct answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164302/get-current-ios-device-orientation-even-if-devices-orientation-locked.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `orientation` to get the current device's orientation,

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
```

To check for *portrait mode*, you can simply do,

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .portrait {
    //add your code here...
}
```

These can be the possible `orientation` values,

```
public enum UIDeviceOrientation : Int {
    case unknown
    case portrait // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
    case portraitUpsideDown // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
    case landscapeLeft // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
    case landscapeRight // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
    case faceUp // Device oriented flat, face up
    case faceDown // Device oriented flat, face down
}
```