# Swift How to get orientation when orientation is locked

Tags: swift, uikit, landscape

the orientation in the app is locked. However, on the news detail page, I need to start the video full screen while in landscape. How can I find out the landscape status?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49164564/4054263) might have a solution you're looking for.

Comment: This answer is not working for me. I couldn't find where to call that method.